# python - sum up list/array according to how another list list/gets assigned by np.histogram

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have two lists of equal lengths `a, b`. I want to create a histogram from `a` and sum up the values of `b` into a new list `c` according to which bin the element of `a` gets assigned to.

```
a = [0.3, 1.2, 1.8, 0.5, ...]
b = [1, 1, 0, 0, ...]

hist = np.histogram(a, bins=[0.0, 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2.])
```

In the example above, `b[0]` would be added to `c[0]` because `a[0]` gets added to `hist[0]`; `b[1]` would be added to `c[2]` etc. What is a scalable way of doing this without using loops? (Loops are too slow for large lists.)

Comment: Loops are too slow for large lists.

How? You can't create `c` without looping over `b` and `a`, you can do this over a single loop, and even speed it up with `numpy` but you can't avoid going looping through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `pandas` for this purpose:

```
import pandas as pd
buckets = pd.cut(a, bins=[0.0,0.5,1, 1.5, 2])

result = pd.Series(b).groupby(buckets).sum()
```

Output:

```
(0.0, 0.5]    1
(0.5, 1.0]    0
(1.0, 1.5]    1
(1.5, 2.0]    0
dtype: int64
```